# What is correct path for attaching file from Android app's local filesystem when using cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing?

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins

[cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) is being used to create a file in an Android app’s local filesystem. The file is successfully created in `/data/data/<app-id>/files/Documents`, which is in the Documents folder under `cordova.file.dataDirectory` as per https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/README.md#android-file-system-layout.

When using [cordova-plugin-email-composer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer), the file is successfully attached to an email by referencing it with `app://files/Documents/fileName.txt`.

However, when using [cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin), the file is **not** successfully attached to the email when using `app://files/Documents/fileName.txt` and various permutations of the path. The email client (Gmail) displays “Can’t attach empty file” or “Permission denied for the attachment”.

Can anyone advise on the specific path that can be used to reach the file using cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing? Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

==

Additional information: When running `console.log(cordova.file.dataDirectory);`, the following value is returned: `file:///data/user/0/<app-id>/files/`.  When using that path to attach the file, the email client displays this error: “Permission denied for the attachment”.

Comment: Why you are not using cordova path `cordova.file.dataDirectory` to attach the file?

Comment: @Avijit: I just added new information to the bottom of the above description based on your comment about using `cordova.file.dataDirectory` to attach the file. Do you have any guidance or feedback you can provide based on that information? Thanks!

Comment: `var options = {
  message: 'share this', 
  subject: 'the subject',
  files: [cordova.file.dataDirectory+ 'fileName.txt'],
  url: 'https://www.website.com/foo/#bar?a=b',
  chooserTitle: 'Pick an app'
}`

Note the files key in options object.
Share your code if this is not working.